# Copy the elements of one array into another array

Tags: arrays, c

This is my code for trying to copy an array into array while printing the copied one.

```
 int arr1[10],arr2[10];
 int i , n ;

 for(i=0; i<n; i++)
 {
     arr1[10]=arr2[10];
 }
 printf("NOW WE WILL PRINT arr2: \n\n");

 for(i=0;i<n;i++)
 {
     printf("%d \n", arr2[i]);
 }
```

It does not work, why?

Comment: ``arr1[10]=arr2[10];`` should be ``arr1[i]=arr2[i];``

Comment: and should be``n = 10``

Comment: Voting to close this for typo

Comment: Note that `arr1` is not initialized.  You are copying (trying to copy) junk into your second array.  But I'm pleased you used the names `arr1` and `arr2` — so often people will use `arr` and `arr2`, which I consider is a bit inconsistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int arr1[10],arr2[10];
int i , n ;
// assigning 10 to n
n = 10;
// initializing arr1
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    arr1[i]=i;
}
// copying elements of arr1 into arr2. we want each element of arr1 to be copied into arr2.
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    arr2[i]=arr1[i];
}
printf("NOW WE WILL PRINT arr2: \n\n");

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    printf("%d \n", arr2[i]);
}
```

I have initialized arr1 and copied the elements of arr1 to arr2 in addition to incorporating the edits pointed out in the comments.

Comment: You could demonstrate avoiding magic numbers. Especially to use an automatic value for `n` and maybe a more suitable name. Also, though you did well crediting the comments, an explanation within the answer would make it better.